# How to write a function that accepts (string|number|null|undefined) but only returns string and possibly null|undefined?

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors

The code below works only when I cast the value. I don't think it should be necessary as long as I check for null and undefined:

```
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return value;
```

Here we know that value can only be null|undefined. So R is the same as T. Even if a variable of type string|null is passen, then is should work:
`T extends (string|number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number>`
If it's string it becomes `string | null` and if it's null it becomes `null`.
So it can only return string|null.

```
  const nr = parseFloat(value as string);
```

Here I have to cast because parseFloat actually just returns NaN for null, undefined, and other non-numbers. That's why the previous check isn't technically necessary.

```
  if(!isFinite(nr)) return value.toString();
```

At this point we know it can only be string|number and we return the same value as a string (in case it is a number).

```
  return nr.toLocaleString(locale);
```

Here we also return a string. Input must be string|number and since number is excluded from T it should work just fine.

Where is the problem with the first method (toLocaleString1)? Shouldn't it compile as well? I tried the compiler to see what type it infers when I call the methods with different variables and the resulting type is always what I expect. So both work just find but I get compilation errors on the first one.

The goal is to have a method that behaves like having these overloads:

- `string => string`
- `string | null => string | null`
- `string | null | undefined => string | null | undefined`
- `string | undefined => string | undefined`
- `string | number => string`
- `string | number | null => string | null`
- `string | number | null | undefined => string | null | undefined`
- `string | number | undefined => string | undefined`
- `number | null => string | null`
- `number | null | undefined => string | null | undefined`
- `number | undefined => string | undefined`
- `null | undefined => null | undefined`
- `null => null`
- `undefined => undefined`

```ts
  // Compiles with errors:
  function toLocaleString1<T extends number|string|null|undefined>(value: T, locale?: string): T extends (string|number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number> {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return value;
    const nr = parseFloat(value as string);
    if(!isFinite(nr)) return value.toString();
    return nr.toLocaleString(locale);
  }

  // does the same but has all these casts:
  function toLocaleString2<T extends number|string|null|undefined, R extends (T extends (string|number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number>) >(value: T, locale?: string): R {
    const nr = parseFloat(value as string);
    if(!isFinite(nr)) return `${value}` as unknown as R;
    return nr.toLocaleString(locale) as unknown as R;
  }

  const TYPES = ['string', 'number', 'null', 'undefined', 'NaN'] as const;

  function value(type: (typeof TYPES)[number] ) : string | number | null | undefined {
    switch(type) {
      case 'string': return "12345.678"; 
      case 'number': return 98765.4321; 
      case 'null': return null; 
      case 'undefined': return undefined; 
      case 'NaN': return NaN; 
    }
  }

  console.log('-------------')
  for (const type of TYPES) {
    const input = value(type);
    const formatted1 = toLocaleString1(input, 'de');
    const formatted2 = toLocaleString2(input, 'fr');
    console.log(type, input, formatted1, formatted2);
  }
```

[run code on typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AC8MKzXo9LBzGh8AOUEr6PAF12+vcAdJWYNgODhYZXFwABPeAfFSSDoOgAYt13EQYgPS9iB-XJIljSoAzac4qimXCnxWLoMXQHBcBYfBwKg1BckTH5gDFEYT1jI9fBHHEACIZGVABmAAWABWeEADYAHYAA5uL2YAMSON5WPQjia2xLgAE4pIksTRME-jlRkOSFOYpSbymVSuK4KZjKY0z0FYkiX042suCcpxbKYlib3fT8XPU4BfM8qkVxpI4TmgNB4WCVEjwAWgSxKksSo8YklchUj-bg6OABC-B3PcGIxLLJHgbkLl2WjoKLcKUx5OhyFgR41A0GQLnHAlFVjGRXFK7lzzsVKh1q04GuIJrcBa5V2vlUIp1kXqmDK3BzzoYghuKiKopiqrUECPqVuAMaJpamRAmO5qnGVItVyAA)

Comment: `I have to cast because parseFloat actually just returns NaN for null, undefined, and other non-numbers.` why do you need to cast. If string is the main return type can't you just return `value.toString()`?

Comment: I've got a short write-up to explain the alternative since this happens a lot... https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse

Comment: TS can't follow the logic involving generic conditional types; this is a current limitation as per [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) (among others).  For now you need what you are calling "casts" (the conventional TS term is *type assertion*). You can do it more simply with a single-call-signature overload as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3VPbN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @kelsny I see. But I don't want 14 overloads. I am not even certain I got them all. I just listed them to show that this would be a ridiculously long list. And my code seems to work fine, so what would be the point?

Comment: @jcalz That looks great. I'd love to learn more about how this works so much better than my code. I'm sure I'd use it a lot. And yes, those are type assertions, not casts. My mistake.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  It doesn't really work "better", it just makes the type checking laxer.  TS really is unable to verify generic conditionals so you either get too-strict (possible errors on safe code) or too-lax (possible acceptance of unsafe code).

Comment: @depperm I can only return `T extends (string|number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number>`, so not a number. I want `null` and `undefined` returned as is and everything else as a string. If it's a finite number, I want it formatted according to given locale. At least in this example. There is more for my project, but for the example this is as simple as it gets. See comment by jcalz for a working solution.

Comment: @kelsny points out an important point about any solution using overloads (extensive overloads or generic single-call-signature overload): The compiler won't check that the implementation actually fits the given types. A solution using type assertions might still be the more robust option. But the single-call-signature overload looks very elegant.

Comment: "A solution using type assertions might still be the more robust option." Why would that be the case? Both overloads and type assertions are making the code checking less strict, why would one be more "robust"?

Comment: Because someone changing the code might assume that the types are all checked by the compiler while using type assertions of the form "as unknown as R" would make it clear that this is not the case. For me when it comes to robustness it's all about reducing the risk of someone (possibly many years in the future) changing the code might mess it up in unintended ways. Way more robust would be to have multiple methods that accept different (union) types. And removing support for "null" as it doesn't seem to make much sense for this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot currently use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type parameters*.  So inside the body of `toLocaleString`, you can check `value` all you want and it might cause the apparent type of `value` to narrow from `T` to something like `null` or `undefined`, but `T` itself will not change.  It turns out to be difficult to change `T` correctly, because it's a type and not a value.  For example, even if we find out that `value` is `null`, it doesn't mean that `T` is `null`; `T` could still be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `string | null`.  All we know for sure about `T` is that it has some *overlap* with `null`, and for now the language doesn't have a facility to express or handle such changes (it's not merely re-[constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraint) `T`).

So `T` stays unchanged, and thus the type `T extends (string | number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number>` can't be reduced to anything more concrete.  The compiler treats it mostly  as an opaque blob of a type, and can't figure out if `null` is or is not an acceptable value of that type in, say, `if (value === null) return value`.  And you get compiler errors at each `return` statement.

There are various open GitHub issues about this limitation; the one most relevant to your example is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which specifically talks about functions that return generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Until and unless that's implemented, you'll need to work around it.

---

The most viable workaround right now is to just accept that the compiler is not smart enough to follow the logic, and use the equivalent of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to loosen the type checking enough to pass.  That is, it becomes *our* responsibility to validate the implementation, because the compiler cannot.

Of course, if you have ten `return` statements you'd need ten type assertions, and that's verbose and annoying.  In cases like this I tend to switch to making my function a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  Overloads are usually meant for multiple call signatures, but here we only have one.  The reason it's helpful is that overloads automatically provide a sort of loose connection between the caller's view of the function and the implementer's view.  And it lets the implementation compile as long is it's *broadly* compatible with the call signatures.

In your case then it might look like

```
function toLocaleString1<T extends number | string | null | undefined>(
  value: T, locale?: string
): T extends (string | number) ? string : never | Exclude<T, number>;

function toLocaleString1(
  value: number | string | null | undefined, locale?: string
): string | null | undefined {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return value;
  const nr = parseFloat(String(value));
  if (!isFinite(nr)) return value.toString();
  return nr.toLocaleString(locale);
}
```

where the implementation is not generic and just returns a union type output from a union type input.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOAZOECGAbApgZSgCcYwBzARgB4AVRXADylzABMBnRMEAWwCNcRRAB9E7YqTIiuIbNmnhWuYKVysAfAAoAUIkQA3HCFwAuRDQA0ibBhy4A-GfEly2gJRm6jZm06bnktLc-IJuiPZiEuSIZmC4+oLSAKIMENggSrRWwQJE6gDc2qCQsAjIaLZ4hC6UmobppjIhQqIB0aLccgpsyqqsVjZYeI6RNR6jgR2y8qKKvXGsiADeuogwwIh1RriIALz7Ml3CovXGewdzKgthRLhQIERIp7iFehAI4lxCu4gADphEdi4ABiNkwUE01UkWwabjcrzWG00AEIYOxgaQYMxNGAiHDELd7o8DNsAHQoKHkTTw1aEh5IXHkipDAhRMiaQZ2GkAX20fKAA)

Comment: Than your for this explanation. It is very helpful.